# hyperledger fabric CA and Softhsm

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I configured hyperledger fabric CA server with softHSM. 
And i am using fabric node sdk when enrolling new user. But i didn't know where are private keys located (generated).

I already checked:

- CA server's docker container's msp/keystore directory
- softHSM tokens directory

Please help me. I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The private key will be stored in the keystore you configured when using the Node SDK.  It is not stored / generated by the Fabric CA.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So how to configure Node SDK to use softHSM when store private keys. Thanks

Comment: @Alemcredits does this test script help you, shows the use of a hsmwallet, registering and enrolling a sample user to submit a trxn -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.4/test/integration/network-e2e/invoke-hsm.js